# Change connection string dynamically from C#

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, connection-string

I would like to know how can I change the connection string dynamically from C# in run time.
I have 3 connection string in the App.config, I would like to know how can I change one of the connections dynamically.

P.S 
I use Ado.NET , Entity Framework.

Comment: Using code first or Entity first approach?

Comment: Did you have a look at [ConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks all of you guys I solved the problem with the help of Anandkumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you want to change the connection string just you change the main connection string in App.Config file.

**[Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/416198/How-to-get-Connection-String-from-App-Config-in-cs)**